# Trouble reading Dockerfile commands: Is it possible to cd into a jar file? and what does tar -cf do?

Tags: java, linux, docker, unix, tar

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV AJSC_HOME=/opt/att/ajsc
ENV AJSC_CONFIG_HOME=${AJSC_HOME}/config

COPY startService.sh /startService.sh
RUN chmod 777 /startService.sh && dos2unix /startService.sh

ADD @project.build.finalName@-@assembly.id@.tar.gz app.jar

ADD prometheus-java-agent.jar monitoring.jar
ADD ilib.jar ilib.jar

RUN (cd app.jar/@project.build.finalName@;tar -cf - src) | (cd ../..;tar -xf -) \
&& (cd app.jar/@project.build.finalName@;tar -cf - opt/att/ajsc/lib) | (cd ../..;tar -xf -) \
&& (cd app.jar/@project.build.finalName@;tar -cf - opt/att/ajsc/config) | (cd ../..;tar -xf -)
RUN (mv monitoring.jar opt/att/ajsc/lib)
RUN (mv ilib.jar opt/att/ajsc/lib)
RUN (rm -rf app.jar)

ENTRYPOINT /startService.sh
```

I understand everything in this file except for the following lines:

```
RUN (cd app.jar/@project.build.finalName@;tar -cf - src) | (cd ../..;tar -xf -) \
&& (cd app.jar/@project.build.finalName@;tar -cf - opt/att/ajsc/lib) | (cd ../..;tar -xf -) \
&& (cd app.jar/@project.build.finalName@;tar -cf - opt/att/ajsc/config) | (cd ../..;tar -xf -)
```

What are those three lines doing? It looks like some directories are simply being copied into specific directories in the docker image, but why "untar" instead of simply using the `COPY` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the title you ask about `cd` into a jar. This does not work, at least in the typical UNIX shell. So most likely it is a directory called `app.jar`, not a jar file. The sequence

```
tar -cf - dir-to-pack | (cd otherdir; tar -xf -)
```

is indeed a recursive copy operation preserving file modes. With regard to special cases like device files, soft links, hard links, there might be a few differences to just using `cp -a`, but whether they are actually intended or merely accidental depends on the craftmanship of the person who prepared the docker image.